# AH00526:Wamp server starting error

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver, apache2.4

I have a fresh install of wampserver2.5-Apache-2.4.9-Mysql-5.6.17-php5.5.12-64bit .But when i click on wampserver it turns orange and fails to start.I checked my logs,all my apache,php and mysql logs seems empty.Browsing the internet ,i found that running the following command **C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin>httpd.exe -e debug** I got the following error logs.

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 16 of C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf:Invalid command 'IndexOptions', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Can someone help me out how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you somehow managed to turn off the `autoindex_module` in `httpd.conf`

Check using the wampmanager menus like so:

```
start WAMPServer
left click wampmanager -> Apache -> Apache modules
```

There should be a line in the menu that shows called `autoindex_module` and it should have a tick beside it.

If the tick is missing just click on the menu item `autoindex_module` and it will activate the module and restart Apache for you. It takes a few second to activate a module, but them wampmanager icon should then go green, unless you have other problems

PS. If MySQL or APache dont start and the log files are empty look in the Windows Event Viewer for messages from `Apache` or `MYSQL`.

#### Launching Windows Event Viewer

- Windows Key + R to launch the run dialog then enter eventvwr.exe and press the OK button
- On the left side of the windows click 'Windows Logs -> Applications'
- Look for the names 'Apache Service' or 'MySQL' in the Source column which have a error symbol in the first column.